# Centering a UILabel inside of a UITableView Header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I added my UIView as a UITableView header, but when I did, my constraints fell apart. I am trying to have my `chapterVerseLabel` centered inside the circle as so :

[image]

I accomplish this thus so far by doing this :

```
    var allConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    let views = ["tableView" : tableView, "containerView" : containerView, "chapterVerseLabel" : chapterVerseLabel]
    allConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-70-[chapterVerseLabel]-70-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(allConstraints)
```

But I'm not sure how to get it centered as well. It seems all my attempts to center it, don't abide by the stricter rules of centering something within a UITableView Header.

All ideas welcome.

---

**Update**

I tried adding a .CenterX value :

```
    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: chapterVerseLabel, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    containerView.addConstraint(leftConstraint)
    let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: chapterVerseLabel, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    containerView.addConstraint(rightConstraint)
```

But this is the result :

[image]

Right now, the chapterVerseLabel sits within my containerView, which is assigned as the `tableView.tableHeaderView` . Like so :

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = containerView
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 1: Are you sure your label is a subview of the header view and not some other view inside it? 2: You probably want a centerX constraint in addition to changing your constraints to: `V:|-(>=70)-[chapterVerseLabel]-(>=70)-|`

Comment: @DanielGalasko Sorry, you're absolute right. It is a subview of `containerView` , which is why my constraints broke. Originally I had them working fine as a view separate of my tableView. And then once I made them as the header of the UITableView, all my constraints fell apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your constraint are that you have already bounded the label by giving Top and Bottom constraints. Also i dont see leading and trailing constraints You actually have to align the label vertically or horizontally or both based on your requirement.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *yCS =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:chapterVerseLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
[containerView addConstraint:yCS];

NSLayoutConstraint *xCS =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:chapterVerseLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
[containerView addConstraint:xCS];
```

Assuming containerView is your header view which gets returned from headerforView delegate method. You need to provide height and width to the label.

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense. I'm experimenting with it, but I think my problem is that chapterVerseLabel is inside containerView, which is `self.tableView`'s headerTableView .. I updated my answer above with more info.. I probably should have included it earlier. my apologies.. thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Ah just figured it out based on your answer. I added the constraint to the tableView and it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

There is a uiview at the center. If you want to add a view(1/4) to the circular view at the center you can not do it with the visual format. I assume you want to center `chapterVerseLabel`.
So:

```
chapterVerseLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
yourCircularView.addsubView(chapterVerseLabel)
let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: chapterVerseLabel, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view2, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
superview.addConstraint(xCenterConstraint)

let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: chapterVerseLabel, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view2, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
superview.addConstraint(yCenterConstraint)
```

Comment: what is `view2` in your answer?